# Only draw partial boundary in ParametricPlot

Tags: plotting, style

Consider the following simple plot

```
ParametricPlot[
 ReIm[x*Exp[I*y]], {x, 0, 1}, {y, 0, 2 \[Pi]}
 ]
```

resulting in

[image].

Notice the blue line between $0$ and $1$ corresponding to the boundary $y=0$ and $y=2\pi$. Is there a way to only draw the part of the boundary corresponding to $x=1$ in an "exposed way"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
ParametricPlot[ReIm[x*Exp[I*y]], {x, 0, 1}, {y, 0, 2 π}, 
 BoundaryStyle -> None, 
 MeshFunctions -> {#3 &}, 
 Mesh -> {{{1, Directive[Thick, Opacity[1], Red]}}}]
```

[image]

**Update:** ***"I will need to include "normal" meshes like Mesh->{10,10} in my planned plots as well."***

```
ParametricPlot[ReIm[x*Exp[I*y]], {x, 0, 1}, {y, 0, 2 π}, 
 BoundaryStyle -> Blue, 
 MeshFunctions -> {#3 &, #4 &, #3 &}, 
 MeshStyle -> {Opacity[1, Purple], Opacity[1, Blue], Automatic}, 
 Mesh -> {10, 10, {{1, Directive[Thick, Opacity[1], Red]}}}]
```

[image]

Comment: I did not include a mesh in my MWE. However, I will need to include "normal" meshes like `Mesh->{10,10}` in my planned plots as well. Is there a way to combine such a normal mesh with your proposed workaround meshline?

Comment: @Gragarian, please see the update.